# Debería iniciar la migración de Asp.net MVC a Asp.net MVC core 2.0 o debería esperar que se estabilice el producto?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, .net-core

Compañeros programadores, después de leer varios artículos en Google, aun no me siento confiado en cambiar mis desarrollos a Core, aunque la gran mayoría  afirman que Core es el futuro ( y no lo dudo) , me siento inseguro que la versión 2.0 (o la actual) sea el momento adecuado para iniciar migraciones, no me gustaría pasar con una experiencia como la que tuve con Silverlight,SignalR  (que Microsoft afirmaba que era el futuro y después se descontinuaron),  aparte en algunos artículos mencionaban que habían cambios forzados en cada nueva liberación de Core, y eso me preocupa.

esta es una de mis referencias:
https://rehansaeed.com/is-asp-net-core-now-a-mature-platform/

Agradeceré mucho si me pueden ayudar con mi dilema.

De antemano gracias compañeros

Comment: Amigo, te recomiendo migres sin duda alguna, argumentos sobran, desde que es multiplataforma hasta la diferencia en rendimiento. Sobre la versión ya esta disponible la 2.2 y está bien cocinada. Sobre SignalR te diria que lo uso a dia de hoy y es lo máximo, muy sencillo. no se que habrás leido, pero descontinuado no está

Comment: muchas gracias, ya inicie la travesia, y la verdad esta interesante el cambio, a veces algunos programadores tenemos temor en ser early adopters, con algunas herramientas en especial.
Saludos y gracias